# Failed to build gem native extension using mysql2 without rails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I´m trying to install mysql2 using the CMD but this error keep coming, What could be wrong? This is so confusing :S. I already check on other questions but I can´t find what is wrong
I´m using ruby 3.0.2p107 and MySQL workbench 8.0CE

````
Using msys2 packages: mingw-w64-x86_64-libmariadbclient
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    enter code here
    current directory: C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/ext/mysql2
C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20210928-10716-rfutt6.rb extconf.rb

>checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

>Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysql-config
        --without-mysql-config
        --with-mysqlclient-dir
        --without-mysqlclient-dir
        --with-mysqlclient-include
        --without-mysqlclient-include=${mysqlclient-dir}/include
        --with-mysqlclient-lib
        --without-mysqlclient-lib=${mysqlclient-dir}/lib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `block in find_library': undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `collect'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `find_library'
        from extconf.rb:87:in `<main>'

>To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  >C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/3.0.0/mysql2-0.5.3/mkmf.log

>extconf failed, exit code 1

>Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/3.0.0/mysql2-0.5.3/gem_make.out```
````

Comment: Can you post your mkmf.log? The message is asking you to look there for more info.